# if statement inside a js function not working

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
session_start();
if !(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
$logged = "0";
}
else {
$logged = "1";
}
$logged = json_encode($logged);
// var logged=$logged;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function create( template, vars, opts ){
    return $container.notify("create", template, vars, opts);
}

$(function(){
    // initialize widget on a container, passing in all the defaults.
    // the defaults will apply to any notification created within this
    // container, but can be overwritten on notification-by-notification
    // basis.
    $container = $("#container").notify();


// var logged == <?= $logged; ?>;

//var logged = <?php $logged; ?>;
 if (<?php $logged;?> !=1) {
// var logged = <?= $logged; ?>;
// if (logged != 1) {

    create("sticky", { title:'J~Net Site Message', text:'Welcome To J~Net Site, Enjoy Your Stay'},{ expires:false });
}
```

This snippet sits inside a function and gives blank pages i have setup the session checking in php above the js function any ideas why this js is not working? the $logged should be accessible inside js function correct?

Comment: i have also tryed $logged aswell as logged and also $(if and $if.

Comment: `logged != "0"` and `logged != 0` are not the same

Comment: Can you go to jsfiddle.net and set up an example where we can reproduce this? That will make it much easier for us to help you. Otherwise we have nothing to go off of here since there could be anything going on outside of this snippet. Just as a possibility, you might try taking the quotes off of the '0'. The quotes tell the JS interpreter it is a string while you may really mean that it is a number (no quotes).

Comment: Is `logged` or `$logged` a PHP variable? Or, where is it declared?

Comment: MultiMedia, this is not how this site works. If you have a solution, post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 3):

While your question is somewhat incomplete I infer from your comments that you are trying to use PHP variables inside your Javascript. You can't do that.

The PHP variables are all processed on the server and the Javascript logic is all processed on the client. So if you want a PHP value to get into your JS do something inline like this:

```
if (<?= $logged;?> != "0") {
```

or put the PHP value in a js variable first:

```
var logged = <?= $logged; ?>;
if (logged != "0") {
```

Comment: May want to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) when outputting to lessen the chance of creating syntax errors.

Comment: ok i have now tryed if (<?php echo $logged;?> != "1") {

 create("sticky", { title:'J~Net Site Message', text:'Welcome To J~Net Site, Enjoy Your Stay'},{ expires:false });
}
 and it still dosn't work

Comment: also tryed without the echo and also the same as originally stated in comment

Comment: What isn't working? Is the if statement the problem or the create function? What is the create function? Is is a PHP function you are excepting to work or a JS function? It will only work if it is a JS function.

Comment: ok I tryed all ways described here and it fails i do not know if this changes anything but the original function starts $(function(){

Comment: At this point it will be hard to help you further without seeing more source code or a jsfiddle example (which isn't likely since you have PHP involved).

Comment: I updated the question to show more code, all the commented out secions have been tryed and failed and i am gettin blank pages, the js works and the php works until i add the if statement inside the function.

Comment: Much of your commented out syntax is wrong. Either use <?= $logged;?> or <?php echo $logged;?>